# How to prepend two chars at the beginning of an Int16Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, buffer

For app-specific reasons I need to prepend exactly these two chars 'a,' (the a and one comma) at the beginning of an existing Int16Array

at the moment I tried with this code but it does not seem to work correctly:

```
function convertFloat32ToInt16(buffer) {
    var prefix          = 'a,',
        prefixLength    = prefix.length / 2, // divided by 2 because we deal with 16 bits, not 8 bits
        bufferLength    = buffer.length,
        totalLength     = prefixLength + bufferLength,
        arr             = new Int16Array(totalLength),
        i

    for (i = 0; i < prefixLength; i = i + 2) {
        arr[i] = prefix.charCodeAt(i) + prefix.charCodeAt(i + 1)
    }

    for (i = prefixLength; i < totalLength; i++) {
        arr[i] = Math.min(1, buffer[i - prefixLength]) * 0x7FFF // convert to 16 bit
    }

    return arr.buffer
}
```

Any suggestions how I can do it better and fix the above code?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why use an `Int16Array` if you need to store random characters in it? You're asking for problems doing this.

Why not just use a regular array?  Replace your definition of `arr` with `arr = []`, and replace references to `buffer` with `arr`

In any case, you'll need to use a different data structure if you want to store random characters. You could always make your return line something like this:

```
return {buffer: arr.buffer, type: prefix}
```

Comment: I know what you mean. Cannot do that because it must be an Int16Array. I am converting WebAudio samples, which are initially in Float32, to 16 bit signed integers before sending these to the server. This because endianness does matter.

Comment: Furthermore I am also sending video data to the server. For each of these streams I am adding "a," or "v," at the beginning of the buffer so that the server can distinct between these two before encoding.

Comment: Thanks for trying but it must be a Int16Array to save bandwidth and because audio samples must remain 16 bit.